# How to build video.js

Tags: git, build, video.js

The build.sh has been removed from the source tree and the comment on git under the delete is that you should use rake to build it.  I have attempted and failed to use ruby to build video.js from the source tree.  Anybody have any hints that could help build this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build videojs with rake you need to install the httparty gem

```
gem install httparty
```

Hope that helps out someone else.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the developer](https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/commit/9293076b75a119a1bb4af20e28d86bf7e177549b#commitcomment-2334570), you should be able to build it using Rake using

```
rake build:current
```

If that fails, then you probably have an issue with your Rake setup or dependencies.